# Select values that have different rows matching different conditions?

Tags: sql, relational-division

*This is a canonical question on how to perform a [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division) using a RDBMS as a result of [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281023/what-can-we-do-to-prevent-repeated-relational-division-questions/281041?noredirect=1#comment133430_281041) on Meta. If you need to add more informations, please do not post new answer, but instead edit the community wiki answer.*

---

Consider this table:

```
| student | course  |
+---------+---------+
|  Adam   | Math    |
|  Adam   | Science |
|  John   | Math    |
|  John   | Science |
|  Jane   | Math    |
|  Jane   | Physics |
```

I want to pull all students who are taking both math and science. This means Adam and John should be returned.

Comment: What type of database?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia for this question we're leaving that part open, and will update the community wiki answer as appropriate. See the linked Meta post for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Group by the student and take only those having both courses

```
select student
from your_table
where course in ('math','science')
group by student
having count(distinct course) = 2
```

Comment: This is a great solution, one I've never even thought of. Do you mind adding (or if I add) it to the community wiki answer?

Comment: In fact I answered this very question in at least a hundred variations and this is not really new. :)

Comment: I know it's not. Did you take a look at the meta post?

Comment: I did a quick read just now. I will look for a highly upvoted question like this one. There must be at least one.

Comment: I don't know how you caught that duplicate, but thanks. I just fear that the title doesn't really capture the issue, and so new users may still be unlikely to find it, don't you think?

Comment: @McAdam331 You can edit the title to make it more general and searchable.

Comment: This is likely the best answer as it satisfies the query in only a single scan. There may be configurations of data where two range seeks are superior to a whole table scan, though--but in most cases, the `GROUP BY` solution is superior to a `JOIN` or other pattern that forces two separate table accesses. The problem is only magnified by having more courses in the list... :)

Answer (score 1):

Such operation is called a [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29) and could be defined as the inverse of the `CROSS JOIN` operation. There are various solutions to solve that problem. Some of them may be dependent of your RDBMS. In no particular order:

### Using the `IN` operator

One solution is to write subqueries using the `IN` operator. Start by selecting a list of all students who are taking math, and make sure that student is `IN` the list of all students taking science, like this:

```
SELECT student
FROM enrollment
WHERE course = 'Math'
   AND student IN(
      SELECT student
      FROM enrollment
      WHERE course = 'Science');
```

### Using a `JOIN`

```
SELECT "student"
FROM T t1 JOIN T t2 USING("student")
WHERE t1."course" = 'Math'
  AND t2."course" = 'Science'
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b637c7/3

Comment: This is just opinion, but thumbs down on the `IN` syntax to perform what is basically a `JOIN`. It leads to hard-to-maintain code, and in general, nesting `IN`s is an antipattern that is best replaced with the normal `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @ErikE a join will definitely work here also. Feel free to add to the answer, if you'd like to demonstrate the syntax for a join. There's always more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: If `IN` will not work, I surely would have said "This will not work" instead of "thumbs down on the `IN` syntax." Do you have a response about what I actually *did say*? If not, then my comment stands unopposed--`JOIN` is generally superior to `IN`, especially once you are forced to start nesting the blasted things, and the clarity and correctness of `JOIN` rises up as so patently and blatantly superior.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, SQL Server, and Postgresql, you can use the `intersect` set operator:

```
select student from tbl where course = 'Math'
intersect
select student from tbl where course = 'Science'
```

Comment: This is great relationally, and knowing `INTERSECT` is a good skill! Just know that this will take two different table accesses. Depending on the data, that could be good if both accesses are range seeks, and the `GROUP BY` method has to scan the whole table. However, I would expect (totally opinion based on experience, here) that `INTERSECT` in this case will not perform as well as the `GROUP BY` solution.